# Were these gutters installed correctly?

Tags: gutters

Had these gutters installed last year.  During a rain storm, water runs behind the gutter and down the fascia.   What good is my drip edge doing, if it is BEHIND the gutter?    [image]

Answer (score 4):

This is a common problem when gutters are installed at a later date  after the roof and drip edge are finished.

Ideally, the shingles would be extended over to the gutter but that wasn't done here in anticipation of future gutters.  One solution is to run some caulking between the top edge of the cutter and the drip edge. Another solution, and a better one which I have done, is to get some flashing from your home store and slide it under your bottom row of shingles and overlap the back edge of the gutter. These are solutions that could have been worked out when the gutters were installed if you knew what to look for or if the installer was looking out for you.

Comment: I usually agree with you and most of your answers are spot on.  But in this case I can't agree with using caulking as the PRIMARY defense against water penetration. Heating and cooling of the gutter will cause it to move possibly tearing the caulking. Also, caulking tends to fail over the years, esp. when directly exposed to the weather. Not only that, but part of the fascia board between the roof and gutter  is still exposed to rain water.  You're idea about flashing is much better and that's what I'd do.

Comment: One more comment.  A really bright builder/remodeler  I know insists upon spacers between the gutter and the house to ensure there is air flow along the fascia.  He said he'd replaced way too many fascia boards due to rot behind the gutter.  Of course you need plenty of drip edge to do that, or additional flashing.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson  I listed caulk as a solution but not a primary defense....  I listed the flashing as another solution and a better one which I've done.